# How can i replace document.write?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

This line

```
echo "document.write('". $output ."');\r\n";
```

cause

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script

`$output` load js files from different website

`$output =ob_get_contents();`

When i comment it out, the error dispear, but, the function won't work anymore

How can i replace it ?

Answer (score 0):

I replace it with

```
echo "document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '". $output ."');\r\n";
```

And it worked !